# sqlite equivalent of row_number() over ( partition by ...?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to know if it's possible to do the following using a single sqlite statement:

My table looks something like this:

```
|AnId|UserId|SomeDate|SomeData|
|123 |A     |1/1/2010|aadsljvs|
| 87 |A     |2/9/2010|asda fas|
|193 |A     |2/4/2010|aadsljvs|
|927 |A     |7/3/2010|aadsasdf|
|816 |B     |1/1/2010|aa32973v|
|109 |B     |7/5/2010|aaasfd10|
| 39 |B     |1/3/2010|66699327|
...
```

Each row has a unique id, a user id, a datetime value, and some other data.

I'd like to delete records so I keep the latest 10 records **per user**, based on SomeDate.

In sql server I'd use something like this:

```
delete d
from data d
inner join (
    select UserId
        ,  AnId
        ,  row_number() over ( partition by UserId order by SomeDate desc ) 
              as RowNum
    from data 
) ranked on d.AnId = ranked.AnId
where ranked.RowNum > 10
```

Is there a way to do this in sqlite? The edge case where there are several records with the same SomeDate isn't a particular worry, e.g. if I keep all those records that'd be fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know this question is old, but the following SQLite statement will do what Rory was originally asking for in one statement - Delete all records for a given UserId that are not the 10 most recent records for that UserId (based on SomeDate).

```
DELETE FROM data
WHERE AnId IN (SELECT AnId
               FROM data AS d
               WHERE d.UserId = data.UserId
               ORDER BY SomeDate DESC
               LIMIT -1 OFFSET 10)
```

Comment: Brilliant! And know I know about `OFFSET`.

Comment: I dont see why this is the answer to the original question. He wants to delete the old entries of ALL users and not only for one.

Comment: @Carsten @Jett - It's so long ago I can't remember testing this ... does it even work having an `IN` clause that's correlated to the `data` table? If so then I guess the `IN` gets evaluated separately for each row and therefore it should work for ALL users. But certainly Jett's description isn't what I wanted, i.e. it's not delete records for a **given UserId** but rather for all UserIds. That's what makes it tricky and in SQL Server needs `row_number() over ( partition by ... )`

Answer (score 2):

I needed to fetch the second row for each "object" in a table with a 1 to many relationship to the "object" table.

Usually in SQL this will be done using ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY object_id ORDER BY primary_id DESC)

In Sqlite I had to come up with this voodoo sub-query to get the same result

```
SELECT object_id, MAX(_id)
FROM (SELECT object_id, _id
FROM aTable
EXCEPT
SELECT object_id, MAX(_id)
FROM aTable
GROUP BY object_id)
GROUP BY object_id;
```

Note: The _id is the primary key of aTable and the object table has a 1 to many relationship with the queried table

Answer (score 1):

If you already haven't got the answer.
If it's one table, then you don't need any joins. You can just use:

```
Delete From data
where AnId not in (Select AnId
                   from data
                   Order by SomeDate DESC
                   Limit 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Sqlite 3.25 window functions are supported.
See https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

This might be prohibitively expensive (perhaps only do it when a user inserts a new record?) but how about this:

```
for user in users:
  user-records = select * from records where user=user
  if user-records.length > 10:
    delete from records where user=user and date<user-records[10]
```

(in a mix of SQL and pseudocode)

Comment: Sure, I can do it procedurally, but I want a way to do it in a single statement if possible. If doing it procedurally it would also be possible to use a single statement per user, and only for the users with records in the table

Comment: Ah, yeah; I have no idea then. Out of curiosity, how can you do it in a single statement per-user?

Comment: Well, that's the question! the syntax in the question shows how to do it in sql server. I don't know if this is possible in sqlite. I suspect not.