# Get Offset of ROWID in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, rdbms

How do I get the offset of a particular row in a SQLite3 database? I am not talking about the ROWID, which is not linear, I am talking about the offset/position of a specific ROWID from the first ROWID in the table.

This is something like the `SELECT COUNT(rowid) FROM table WHERE rowid < row`, which returns the number of rows before the row identified with `row`. I feel that this is too slow, so I am hoping there is another way, faster than this, which will give me the offset/position of a row in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1
   rowid
from
   table
where
  rowid < row
order by
  rowid desc
```

That should give you the largest rowid before your row.  You could also try...

```
select
   max(rowid)
from
   table
where
  rowid < row
```

...But in my experience the first option performs better.

If you just want the number of rows in front of your target row.  Use...

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE rowid < row
```

Basically what you had before, but don't specify a column or else it is going to have to check that column for nulls while counting.

Unfortunately, you don't have access to the "ROW_NUMBER()" function like there is in MS SQL.

(Similiar Question regarding SQLLite and numbering)

[sqlite equivalent of row_number() over ( partition by ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074257/sqlite-equivalent-of-row-number-over-partition-by)

Hope this helps.