# How can I numbered each row of the table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm numbering each row of the table

In my program I used the database SQLite

I use the following code in **SQL sever**:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()over (order by len(GoodsID)),  LEN(GoodsID) as 'length' 
FROM inv.tblGoods
GROUP BY LEN(GoodsID)
ORDER BY LEN(GoodsID)
```

I want using the above code in **SQLite** .

But I do not know the equivalent   **ROW_NUMBER**  ?

Any help on either of these is greatly appreciated!

Comment: first hit in a ten second search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074257/sqlite-equivalent-of-row-number-over-partition-by

Answer (score 1):

you can implement it by creating another column in your table like this

```
row_number integer primary key autoincrement
```

Then get the row number by `select row_number`

Comment: But I want the numbering to the search results