# How to renumber a table column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table sorted by column `ID`. But I need to sort it by another numerical field called `RunTime`.

```
CREATE TABLE Pass_2 AS
SELECT RunTime, PosLevel, PosX, PosY, Speed, ID
FROM Pass_1
```

The table `Pass_2` looks good, but I need to renumber the `ID` column from `1 .. n` without resorting the records.

Comment: What do you mean by "reorder (NOT resort) the ID column from 1..n without resorting the records."? Either you sort the rows, or you don't sort.

Answer (score 2):

It is a principle of SQL databases that the underlying tables have *no natural or guaranteed order* to their records.  You must specify the order in which you want to see the records when `SELECT`ing from a table using an `ORDER BY` clause.

You can obtain the records you want using `SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY RunTime`, and that is the correct and reliable way to do this in any SQL database.

If you want to *attempt* to get the records in `Pass_2` to "be" in RunTime order, you can add the `ORDER BY` clause to the `SELECT` you use to create the table but remember: **you are not guaranteed to get the records back in the order in which they were added to the table**.

When might you get the records back in a different order?  This is most likely to happen when your query can be answered using columns in a covering index -- in that case the records are more likely to be returned in index order than any "natural" order (but again, no guarantees with an `ORDER BY` clause).

Comment: Just imagine a column in a table with values of '1, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7...'.  I want to overwrite the column with new values '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...'.

Comment: What is the `ORDER BY` clause that produced the list `1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 7`?

Comment: Also, see this page https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for the possibility of using SQLite's hidden `rowid` column as a possible *proxy* for added-to-table order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new `ID` column starting at `1`, then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.  Instead of `ID` in your query use this `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Runtime) AS ID....` This will replace the old `ID` column with a freshly calculated column

Comment: Sorry for lack of formatting, damn iPads....hard to use the code formats....EDIT thanks for tidying it up

Comment: This is potentially not available in SQLlite ... Unsure whether ROW_NUMBER is supported. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074257/sqlite-equivalent-of-row-number-over-partition-by