# Multiple cumulative sums

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Hopefully the title is explicit enough.

I have a table looking like that :

```
classes id value
a       1  10
a       2  15
a       3  12
b       1  5
b       2  9
b       3  7
c       1  6
c       2  14
c       3  6
```

and here is what I would like :

```
classes id value cumsum
a       1  10    10
a       2  15    25
a       3  12    37
b       1  5     5
b       2  9     14
b       3  7     21
c       1  6     6
c       2  14    20
c       3  6     26
```

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120639/4348534), and I've already applied it successfully to cases where I don't have multiple classes :

```
id value cumsum
1  10    10
2  15    25
3  12    37
```

It was reasonably fast, even with datasets of size equivalent to the one I'm currently working on.

However, when I try to apply the exact same code to the dataset I'm working on now (which looks like the first table of this question, IE multiple classes), without subsetting it by `a`,`b`,`c`, it seems to me that it's taking ages (it's been running for 4 hours now. The dataset is 40.000 rows).

Any idea if there is an issue with the code from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2120639/4348534), when used in this context ? I have trouble wrapping my head around the triangular join thingy, but I have the feeling there might be an issue with the [size the join takes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/60612) when the number of rows increases, thus slowing the whole thing a lot, which maybe is even worsened by the fact that there are multiple "classes" on which to do the cumulative sums.

Is there any way this could be done faster ? I'm using `SQL` in `R` through the `SQLDF` package. A solution in either R code (with or without an external common package) or SQL code will do.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: In base R, it'd be `with(df, ave(value, classes, FUN = cumsum))`

Comment: For close vote, unsure on which way it should be duped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, you can do a cumulative sum using the ANSI standard `sum() over ()` functionality:

```
select classes, id, value,
       sum(value) over (partition by classes order by id) as cumesum
from t;
```

Comment: `sqldf` package uses sqlite, so above might not work. Relevant post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074257/sqlite-equivalent-of-row-number-over-partition-by

Comment: sqldf uses sqlite *by default* but sqldf can use PostgreSQL in which case the above should work.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use `by` from the `base` package:

```
df$cumsum <- unlist(by(df$value, df$classes, cumsum))
#  classes id value cumsum
#1       a  1    10     10
#2       a  2    15     25
#3       a  3    12     37
#4       b  1     5      5
#5       b  2     9     14
#6       b  3     7     21
#7       c  1     6      6
#8       c  2    14     20
#9       c  3     6     26
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to be working (I might be doing something wrong). I'm not sure but it seems to be doing the cumulative over the whole thing and not `by` each class. Here is what I do : `df[with(df, order(classes, another_value, decreasing = TRUE))]` and then `df$cumsum <- unlist(by(df$value, df$classes, cumsum))`

Comment: What is `another_value`? The code is working with your example dataset.

Comment: `another_value` is `id` for instance, a column on which I want to order. (NB : there is another trouble, it doesn't to be doing the cumulative sum over the `value` column...)

Comment: You can ask a new question, given you provide example data and code.